# Google Chrome extension icon sizes

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons

I'm having with getting the correct icons to show in my chrome extension.
To make some tests I'm using the following icon pack where each icon is just a number displaying the size of the icon (i've added a 32 version as well):
https://github.com/jbrudvik/chrome-extension-icon-sizes

I then set my manifest like so:

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "img/icon16.png",
      "19": "img/icon19.png",
      "24": "img/icon24.png",
      "32": "img/icon32.png"
      "38": "img/icon38.png",
      "48": "img/icon48.png"
    },
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "img/icon16.png",
    "19": "img/icon19.png",
    "24": "img/icon24.png",
    "32": "img/icon32.png",
    "38": "img/icon38.png",
    "48": "img/icon48.png",
    "128": "img/icon128.png"
  },
```

What this shows me is that on my mac, under chrome v67:
- The favicon on a tab belonging to the extension uses: 32x32
- The extensions management page uses: 48x48
- The browser action icon uses: 32x32

Google gives some hints as to which sizes get used in which locations:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/icons

I have three questions:

1. Google states that the extensions management page uses the 48x48. However, this does not seem to be the ideal choice for this, as it tends to upscale the image making it look rather blurry. I've found if I remove the 48x48 option from my manifest, or alternatively, provide a 128x128 img for 48x48 option (ie: `"48": "img/icon128.png",`) then this results in a nice clear image. Why doesn't the extensions management page default to using the 128x128 image first? Are there any downsides to my hack of providing at 128x128 image as the defined 48x48 one?
2. Google also states that you can provide a 16x16 icon which will "be used as the favicon for an extension's pages". This contradicts my findings where it actually uses the 32x32 as it's preferred size (falling back on 48x48 if unavailable, and then 128x128).
3. Finally, I haven't tested this, but I suspect these findings may be specific to my computer / operating system. Is it possible that other systems may exhibit different behaviour?

Comment: Basic sizes for modern versions of Chrome are 16 (toolbar icon) and 48 (management icon) but for HiDPI/Retina you need separate entries 32 and 96. As for 128 and its 256 HiDPI buddy, the link says it's used on install.